# ¿Cual es el error de este algoritmo?

Tags: c#, c++, algoritmos, condiciones

Quisiera ver si me pudieran ayudar a encontrar el error en este algoritmo, el ejercicio dice que calcule el descuento: si m>=300 el descuento es del 25% - si 150<=m y m<300 el descuento es del 2% - si m<150 no hay descuento. El problema  que tengo es que me toma todos los descuentos. Acá les dejo el programa, estoy programando en C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () {
    int monto,desc1,calc1,desc2,calc2;

    printf("Ingrese el monto: ");
    scanf("%d",&monto);
    if (monto>300)
    calc1=monto*0.25;
    desc1=monto-calc1;
    printf("El descuento es de: %d $",calc1);
    printf("\nEL total a pagar es de: %d $",desc1);
    else if ((monto<=150 && monto<300)) 
    calc2=monto*0.2;
    desc2=monto-calc2;
    printf("El descuento es de: %d $",calc2);
    printf("\nEl total a pagar es de: %d $",desc2);
    if (monto<150)
    printf("No hay descuento");
    printf("\nEl total a pagar es de: %d $",monto);
}
```

Comment: Los bloques `if` no tienen llave de apertura y cierre? o es un error al copiar el código

Comment: Hola, no tienen llave de apertura y cierre porque cuando los puse no hacia ningun efecto.

Comment: ahi puse bien las llave y me anduvo! Gracias Patricio!

Comment: @GustavoTorres si alguna de las respuestas te sirvio, por favor tomate el tiempo de marcarla como aceptada, porque ellos se tomaron el tiempo en contestar tu duda. GRACIAS!

Comment: como hago eso? perdon, es que soy nuevo en la pagina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te había comentado faltaban las llaves de apertura y cierre de cada bloque, pero además tenías mal la segunda condición `if ((monto<=150 && monto<300))` que te acabo de corregir. Unos comentarios.

1. C y C++ no inicializan los valores de las variables por lo que siempre es una buena práctica inicializarlas luego de declararlas: `int monto=0,desc1=0,calc1=0,desc2=0,calc2=0;`
2. Agregué un "casteo" a `int` en el cálculo del descuento: `int (monto*0.25)` para evitar warnings durante la compilación y de paso te comento que estás perdiendo la parte decimal del calculo al usar `int` pero me imagino es lo que pide el ejercicio.
3. Como ya comentó @Trauma la condición final es innecesaria

El código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () 
{
    int monto=0,desc1=0,calc1=0,desc2=0,calc2=0;

    printf("Ingrese el monto: ");
    scanf("%d",&monto);

    if (monto>300) {
        calc1=int (monto*0.25);
        desc1=monto-calc1;
        printf("El descuento es de: %d $",calc1);
        printf("\nEL total a pagar es de: %d $",desc1);
    }
    else if ((monto>=150 && monto<300)) {
         calc2=int (monto*0.2);
         desc2=monto-calc2;
         printf("El descuento es de: %d $",calc2);
         printf("\nEl total a pagar es de: %d $",desc2);
    } else {
        printf("No hay descuento");
        printf("\nEl total a pagar es de: %d $",monto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberia estar asi

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main () {
    int monto,desc1,calc1,desc2,calc2;

    printf("Ingrese el monto: ");
    scanf("%d",&monto);
    if (monto>300){
       calc1=monto*0.25;
       desc1=monto-calc1;
       printf("El descuento es de: %d $",calc1);
       printf("\nEL total a pagar es de: %d $",desc1);
    }
    else if ((monto<=150 && monto<300)){ 
       calc2=monto*0.2;
       desc2=monto-calc2;
       printf("El descuento es de: %d $",calc2);
       printf("\nEl total a pagar es de: %d $",desc2);
    }
    else (monto<150){
       printf("No hay descuento");
       printf("\nEl total a pagar es de: %d $",monto);
    }
}
```